# How to set initial values for the prior model in a mix mode from DepmixS4 package in R?

Tags: r, mixed-model

I am trying to figure out how to add a concomitant variable in the mix model in DepmixS4 package in R. My model looks like below

```
M1_ss<- mix(list(X1_1~1,X1_2~1,X1_3~1,X2~1,X3~1),
 family = list(multinomial("identity"),
               multinomial("identity"),
               multinomial(),
 gaussian(), 
 gaussian()), 
 data = data,
 nstates = 4, #This is the number of classes
 instart=as.vector(c(0.1,0.4,0.2,0.5,0.2,5,2,0.5)),
respstart=as.vector(c(0.85,0.15,0.9,0.1,0.04,0.7,0.26,-2,0.2,0,0.5,
                      0.6,0.4,0.7,0.3,0.26,0.46,0.3,0,0.3,0.1,0.3,
                      0.35,0.65,0.4,0.6,0.33,0.33,0.34,1,0.5,2,0.1,                             0.1,0.9,0.2,0.8,0.25,0.24,0.51,2,0.2,2.5,0.2)),
 initdata =data,
prior=~c1
)
```

in which, c1 is the concomitant variable I create when generating the dt. Here is the code of creating c1:

```
c1 = rnorm(I,0,1)
Beta10 = 0.1
Beta20 = 3
Beta30 = 5

Beta11 = 0.5
Beta21 = 2
Beta31 = 5

Denominator= 1+exp(Beta11*c1+Beta10)+exp(Beta21*c1+Beta20)+exp(Beta31*c1+Beta30)
#Calculating the matrix of probabilities for three states
vProb2 = cbind(1/Denominator, exp(Beta11*c1+Beta10)/Denominator, exp(Beta21*c1+Beta20)/Denominator ,exp(Beta31*c1+Beta30)/Denominator)

#Assigning the value one to maximum probability and zero for rest-->the states 
mChoices = t(apply(vProb2, 1, rmultinom, n = 1, size = 1))
#combine states and c1 
dfM = cbind.data.frame(State = apply(mChoices, 1, function(x) which(x==1)), c1)
```

long words short, if I run a multinomial logit model of state on c1, the parameters should be close enough to the betas.

However, I come across difficulties in adding the initial values. I cannot add a respstart for all parameters (including the probabilities), I need to add separate initial values for the prior model.I try to add initial values to instart (as shown in the codes above), however, I got very weird results:

[image]
Can I get some help in setting the initial values? I appreciate it a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

The code given in not reproducible without the data and seed. Next time, providing a reproducible example would be very helpful.

Providing initial parameters for the component/class probabilities, when also using a covariate to model these, is not completely straightforward. The first K values (if K is the number of states/components) are treated as probabilities of the states when the covariate has the value 0. These are transformed back to the scale of the multinomial regression model. The remaining values are then the slopes of the covariate(s), and these are left as provided. If you know the values of the intercepts of the multinomial regression you want to get, you can use the inverse of the multinomial logistic link function, as follows:

```r
instart = c(multinomial()$linkinv(c(0,.1,3,5),base=1), 0, .5, 2, 5)
```

Note that it is important to fix all slopes of the baseline level (by default the first level) to 0. So element 5 here is set to 0. As another way to set the values of parameters, you can first define the model, and then use the `setpars` function to set all the model parameters in one go.

I tried setting the initial values as above, and did not get an error. Full code for a reproducible example is

```r
library(depmixS4)

#### start code as given in original question

set.seed(1)

I <- 1000 # guess the number of observations

c1 = rnorm(I,0,1)
Beta10 = 0.1
Beta20 = 3
Beta30 = 5

Beta11 = 0.5
Beta21 = 2
Beta31 = 5

Denominator= 1+exp(Beta11*c1+Beta10)+exp(Beta21*c1+Beta20)+exp(Beta31*c1+Beta30)
#Calculating the matrix of probabilities for three states
vProb2 = cbind(1/Denominator, exp(Beta11*c1+Beta10)/Denominator, exp(Beta21*c1+Beta20)/Denominator ,exp(Beta31*c1+Beta30)/Denominator)

#Assigning the value one to maximum probability and zero for rest-->the states 
mChoices = t(apply(vProb2, 1, rmultinom, n = 1, size = 1))
#combine states and c1 
dfM = cbind.data.frame(State = apply(mChoices, 1, function(x) which(x==1)), c1)

### end code as given in original question

# starting values (from original question)
respstart <- c(
  0.85,0.15,0.9,0.1,0.04,0.7,0.26,-2,0.2,0,0.5,
  0.6,0.4,0.7,0.3,0.26,0.46,0.3,0,0.3,0.1,0.3,
  0.35,0.65,0.4,0.6,0.33,0.33,0.34,1,0.5,2,0.1,  
  0.1,0.9,0.2,0.8,0.25,0.24,0.51,2,0.2,2.5,0.2
)


# generate responses from states and starting values
dfM$X1_1 <- dfM$X1_2 <- dfM$X1_3 <- dfM$X2 <- dfM$X3 <- 0
for(i in 1:4) {
  dfM$X1_1[dfM$State == i] <- sample(1:2,prob=respstart[(i-1)*11 + 1:2],size=sum(dfM$State == i),replace=TRUE)
  dfM$X1_2[dfM$State == i] <- sample(1:2,prob=respstart[(i-1)*11 + 3:4],size=sum(dfM$State == i),replace=TRUE)
  dfM$X1_3[dfM$State == i] <- sample(1:3,prob=respstart[(i-1)*11 + 5:7],size=sum(dfM$State == i),replace=TRUE)
  dfM$X2[dfM$State == i] <- rnorm(sum(dfM$State == i), mean = respstart[(i-1)*11 + 8], sd=respstart[(i-1)*11 + 9])
  dfM$X3[dfM$State == i] <- rnorm(sum(dfM$State == i), mean = respstart[(i-1)*11 + 10], sd=respstart[(i-1)*11 + 11])
}
dfM$X1_1 <- as.factor(dfM$X1_1)
dfM$X1_2 <- as.factor(dfM$X1_2)
dfM$X1_3 <- as.factor(dfM$X1_3)

# define mixture model
M1 <- mix(list(X1_1~1,X1_2~1,X1_3~1,X2~1,X3~1),
            family = list(multinomial("identity"),
                          multinomial("identity"),
                          multinomial("identity"),
                          gaussian(), 
                          gaussian()), 
            data = dfM,
            nstates = 4, #This is the number of classes
            instart=as.vector(c(multinomial()$linkinv(c(0,.1,3,5),base=1), 0, .5, 2, 5)),
            respstart=respstart,
            initdata = dfM,
            prior=~c1
)

# fit mixture model

fM1 <- fit(M1)
```

Note that I set the third multinomial model to use an identity link function as well, which fits in with your starting values. The results I obtained are

````
> summary(fM2)
Mixture probabilities model 
Model of type multinomial (mlogit), formula: ~c1
Coefficients: 
            St1        St2      St3      St4
(Intercept)   0  0.4998085 3.083189 5.103724
c1            0 -0.2898229 1.585633 4.646204
Probalities at zero values of the covariates.
0.005287924 0.008716643 0.1154243 0.8705712 

Response parameters 
Resp 1 : multinomial 
Resp 2 : multinomial 
Resp 3 : multinomial 
Resp 4 : gaussian 
Resp 5 : gaussian 
        Re1.1     Re1.2     Re2.1     Re2.2      Re3.1     Re3.2     Re3.3 Re4.(Intercept)
St1 0.5365853 0.4634147 0.6829268 0.3170732 0.39024387 0.3170732 0.2926829     0.008881159
St2 0.8316832 0.1683168 0.8712872 0.1287128 0.01980198 0.6732673 0.3069307    -2.006661064
St3 0.3632810 0.6367190 0.4184541 0.5815459 0.39292332 0.2995389 0.3075378     1.056042466
St4 0.1191387 0.8808613 0.1884620 0.8115380 0.24334594 0.2468068 0.5098473     1.998233692
       Re4.sd Re5.(Intercept)    Re5.sd
St1 0.3072506      0.09485414 0.2270024
St2 0.1788700      0.05197931 0.5075318
St3 0.5552520      2.00072459 0.1032036
St4 0.2075816      2.49949647 0.1973724
```
````

Comment: Many Thanks, mspeek!!!!!  This is just awesome!! I appreciate the clear, detailed answer a lot!!!!!